# limit access of webservice to localhost using jetty 9 configuration

Tags: jetty

I am using jetty 9 to run my web app. Basically, there is a web app( abc) which runs on port 8443.This webapp abc.war is deployed in jetty 9 server.

Now,there was a requirement to come up with a new web service(say xyzWebService). This new web service runs in the same jetty server as above.We actually created xyzWebService.jar and added it to the abc.war.(lib folder). Now, the problem is that this webservice should be accessed by local host clients only.But the war can be accessed by any client.

I thought of adding connector to jetty, and now my jetty listens on two ports. one is 8443 and another is 9797.But, i am not able to figure out a way , where in , say, I can restrict 9797 port for localhost web service clients only . 
I actually explored adding below content to jetty-web.xml.  Virtual hosts, according to my understanding, expects both contexts to be a separate web app. But in our case,  webservice is a jar and part of the abc webapp.

> 127.0.0.1
>          localhost
>          www.acme.com

PS: i CANNOT expose my WebService as a war ,because this webservice and "abc" app shares some singleton classes.

Please let me know what can be done.  I want to take a configuration approach.